# How to make whole html input type date field clickable for calendar popup?

Tags: javascript, html

In the HTML input type date field when we click on an icon, the calendar is popup. But I want to make it pop up when we click in the dd/mm/yyyy field?
[image: I want to make calendar popup when clicked on this marked field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the `focus` event on the element, then invoke the [`HTMLInputElement.showPicker()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker):

```js
document.getElementById("datePicker").addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  event.target.showPicker();
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePicker" />
```

<sup>**Note:** Unfortunately this doesn't work in the snippet above due to the restrictions of calling `showPicker()` cross-origin combined with the cross-origin implications of the Stack Snippets feature itself, but should work in practice.</sup>

**However**, you should consider that this particular method has relatively abysmal support (only [~66% of all browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlinputelement_showpicker) implement it as of this writing).